# Powershell retrieve credentials from array

Tags: powershell, office365

I am currently using powershell to manage multiple Office 365 tennancies. The biggest time sink is logging out of the Office 365 account in powershell and logging into the different one.

Is there any way I can create a local CSV containing all username and passwords and then when I use Get-Credential, it can look up the CSV for the username and autofill the password?

Any advice or guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: I think creating csv with usernames and password is not the best way to go from a security point of view

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes, it is possible.

But it's not advised to keep the passwords in clear text. Perhaps you could write an example of what you want to achieve, and ask for help if you need help debugging it.

Please seek out information on for example this site, which explains the usage, encryption/decryption to and from secure strings
http://www.travisgan.com/2015/06/powershell-password-encryption.html

I recently used the same source of information to build a solution for a problem not unlike the one you describe above.